# How to match substring or whole string

Tags: python, regex

In Python regex, how would I match only the `facebook.com...777` substrings given either string? I don't want the `?sfnsn=mo` at the end.
I have `(?<=https://m\.)([^\s]+)` to match everything after the `https://m.`. I also have `(?=\?sfnsn)` to match every thing in front of `?sfnsn`.

How do I combine the regex to only return the facebook.com...777 part for either string.

have: `https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=123456789&id=7777777777?sfnsn=mo`
want: `facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=123456789&id=7777777777`

have: `https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=123456789&id=7777777777`
want: `facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=123456789&id=7777777777`

Here's what I was messing around with https://regex101.com/r/WYz5dn/2

```
(?<=https://m\.)([^\s]+)(?=\?sfnsn)
```

Comment: Are you sure your first URL is correct?

Comment: Please tick mark the answer, if it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a capturing group instead of a positive lookbehind and match either `?sfnsn` or the end of the string.

```
https://m\.(\S*?)(?:\?sfnsn|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xijPiJ/1)

Using the lookarounds, the pattern could be:

```
(?<=https://m\.)\S*?(?=\?sfnsn|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5F9add/1)

Answer (score -1):

Putting a `?` at the end works, since the last grouped lookahead may or may not exist, we put a question mark after it:

`(?<=https://m\.)([^\s]+)(?=\?sfnsn)?`